# Process.Start random stops during the middle of the execution

Tags: c#, process, redirectstandardoutput

I need to call an external program to download e-mails into a folder. This external program is a `Java` compiled with Excelsior JET (Jar to Exe).

This is how I call:

```
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        Arguments = Arguments(folder),
        FileName = Path.Combine(@"C:/Fakepath"), "GetMail.exe"),
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    }
};

process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
var outputError = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

//if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(output))
//    LogWriter.Log("GetMail", output.Trim());

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outputError))
      LogWriter.Log("GetMail Erro", outputError.Trim());

process.Close();
```

I guess it has something wrong with the output, like [this other thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471656/why-does-ffmpeg-stop-randomly-in-the-middle-of-a-process).

The `Java` app stops where it shouldn't, like, between two Log calls:

```
try
{
    for (Address addr : msg.getFrom())
    {
        AppConfig.getLogControl().WriteLog("\tFrom.............:" + addr);
    }
} catch (Exception e) { }

MimeMessage msgMIME = null;

try
{
    AppConfig.getLogControl().WriteLog("\tTesting message type... ");
    msg.isMimeType("text/*");
    AppConfig.getLogControl().WriteLog("\t\tMultipart type");
} catch (MessagingException ex)
{
    AppConfig.getLogControl().WriteLog("\t\tMIME type");
    AppConfig.getLogControl().WriteLog("\tDownloading data... ");
    msgMIME = TrataMimeMessage(msg);
}
```

It prints "From...." and stops, if I kill the `C#` process, the `Java` app continues to print the rest.

### Edit

After [reading this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), I think I know what I'm doing it wrong.
One of the sections of the MSDN page:

```
 // To avoid deadlocks, always read the output stream first and then wait.
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As so often, you're redirecting the output / error streams without reading them. When the target application fills its own output buffers, it will hang while trying to write anything more to output.

You need to read the streams, always. For example,

```
var outputTask = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
var errorTask = p.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync();

var output = await outputTask;
var error = await errorTask;
```

No need for `WaitForExit` either - that's what the `ReadToEnd` is for. Although I do tend to use it anyway - but it *must* be after you start reading the output, otherwise you're doomed.

That's like the third time I've seen the exact same wrong snippet in the last week or so. Where do you get those blatantly wrong code samples? :D

If you can't use `await`, this actually gets a bit tricky. The easiest way to handle this is to stop redirecting the error stream (it's not all that well used anyway) and only redirect standard output. Then you can simply do

```
p.Start();

var output = p.ReadToEnd();
```

Note the lack of `WaitForExit` - you *must* read the stream, otherwise you deadlock. The process tries to write to output, but its output buffer is full. You only start reading the output after the process exits, but it cannot exit until you read the output. Again, `WaitForExit` is fine, but use it *after* the `ReadToEnd`.